# javascript / jquery / rest api with parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest, parse-platform

I am using javascript and jquery to send a simple text push notification via parse.com using their rest api. 
This works :-

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': "1234567890",
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': "1234567890"
    },
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
    data: '{"channel": "","type":"ios","expiration_interval":86400,"data":{"alert":"canned alert","badge" :0,"sound":""}}',
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

But this does not:-

```
 var my_msg = "canned alert";
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     headers: {
         'X-Parse-Application-Id': "1234567890",
         'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': "1234567890"
     },
     url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
     data: '{"channel": "","type":"ios","expiration_interval":86400,"data":{"alert":my_msg,"badge" :0,"sound":""}}',
     contentType: "application/json"
 });
```

I cannot find a way to replace successfully send an alert with a variable instead of "canned alert". I am not an experienced programmer but even the parse.com tesch support could not explain why; can anyone suggest a solution please?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "does not work" means in this context? Did you get an error response back, or was it a successful request but no push notifications were delivered?

Answer (score 2):

Take the my_msg variable out of the single quotes in the second snippet, and it should behave exactly like the first one:

```
data: '{"channel": "","type":"ios","expiration_interval":86400,"data":{"alert":'+my_msg+',"badge" :0,"sound":""}}',
```

The way you wrote the second snippet, it looks like you confused a JSON string with an object literal.

Comment: Could you flesh out your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to build the JSON from a plain object:

```
var my_msg = "canned alert";
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':"1234567890",'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':"1234567890"},
  url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "channel": "",
    "type":"ios",
    "expiration_interval": 86400,
    "data":{
      "alert": my_msg,
      "badge" :0,
      "sound":""
    }
  }),
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Using `JSON.stringify` will ensure that any special characters in "my_msg" will be correctly escaped, so that your JSON is guaranteed to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data as an object, no need of any quotes, jQuery will take care of it:

```
var my_msg = "canned alert";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': "1234567890",
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': "1234567890"
    },
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
    data: {
        channel: "",
        type: "ios",
        expiration_interval: 86400,
        data: {
            alert: my_msg,
            badge: 0,
            sound: ""
        }
    },
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that that API correctly deals interprets HTTP parameters?  (It might; I don't know for sure.)

Comment: I have always used it this way. I'm not sure if it were JSONP though, but POST should be ok. Documentation says `The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string`

Comment: Yes, I know that jQuery itself works like that - what I don't know is whether the API that's being called (parse.com?) wants a JSON blob or name/value HTTP parameters. (Note that the OP says that sending a complete JSON string that's not dynamic *did* work.)